# 出力したいのに何も表示されない

Tags: python

クラスと関数について、以下のサイト通りにほとんどやったのですが、体重が5に＋1されて出力されません。

[第9章 Pythonのクラス｜Python入門 - Newmonz](https://newmonz.jp/lesson/python-basic/chapter-9)

写真のようにコードを記入して、関数の `eat` を実行したら "みるくさんの体重は6kgです。"と出力したいですが何も表示されません。
何が間違っているか分かりません。

[image: コード画像]

Comment: コードは画像ではなくテキスト（マークダウン）で記入してください。

Comment: コードの内容については「関数のeatを実行したら、"みるくさんの体重は6kgです。"と出力したいですが、何も出ません。」とのことですが、まず出力するコードがないように見受けられます。コードは上記で全てですか？

Comment: はい。全てです。出力するコードが無いとはどういうことでしょうか？

Comment: 「出力するコードが無いとはどういうことでしょうか？ 」について、print文が質問のコードには無い、という意味です。
「こちらのサイト通りにほとんどやったのですが」とのことですが、「サイト通り」にはなってませんよ。

再度言いますが、コードは画像ではなくテキスト（マークダウン）で記入してください。（回答者がコードを検証しやすくなるからです）

Comment: 参照先の [コンストラクタ \_init\_()](https://newmonz.jp/lesson/python-basic/chapter-9#section-4) を基に改造していると思われますが、単純に見た目が違っているのが明確でしょう。いったん参照先のとおりに入力・実行して確認してから改造してみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

インデント合わせて、milk=Cat("みるく",5)(milkは小文字）にして、return文もprint文にしてmilk.name,milk.weightに入力すればできます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

質問のコードが画像で貼られているため検証はしていません。[参考にされたサイト](https://newmonz.jp/lesson/python-basic/chapter-9)との違いは下記です。自身のコードとよく見比べて修正しましょう。

1. インデントが異なる。Pythonはインデントが重要です。
2. print()の有無です。
3. return文は参考サイトには有りません。

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます！